# Unable to locate element radio botton in Selenium webdriver

Tags: java, selenium, xpath

I am a newbie trying to learn automation using the tool `Selenium`. I am trying to automate this website -
http://newtours.demoaut.com/

where I login and try to access this radio button (one way, round way )for flight finder.
But i am getting the error `Unable to locate the element`.

Tried the following.

1. Tried to locate the element using `Xpath` obtained from `firebug`.
2. Used the following Xpath composed from the `html` code to locate the radio button

   ```
   //*[@type='radio']//*[@value='oneway']

   //*[contains(@type,'radio')]

   //*[contains(text(),'oneway']

   //input[@type='radio' AND @value='oneway']
   ```
3. Also tried `CSS selector` to locate the element.

   ```
   driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("input[type=radio][value=oneway]"))
   ```
4. Tried adding wait times using `implicit wait` and `thread.sleep`

The `HTML` script for the radio button as obtained from `firebug` is -

```
input type="radio" checked="" value="roundtrip" name="tripType"

          Round Trip       

input type="radio" value="oneway" name="tripType"

              One Way
```

Given below is my code -

```
package gurutrial2;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;
import org.testng.Assert;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeTest;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

public class gurutrial2 
{

    public static WebDriver driver;

    @BeforeTest

    public final void preTest() {

        System.setProperty("webdriver.firefox.marionette", "C:/Users/serajendran/Downloads/geckodriver-0.10.0 (1)");
        DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.firefox();
        capabilities.setCapability("marionette", true);

        driver = new FirefoxDriver(capabilities);

        driver.get("http://newtours.demoaut.com/");
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        System.out.println(driver.getTitle());

        Assert.assertEquals("Welcome: Mercury Tours", driver.getTitle());
    }

    @Test
    public final void login() {

        driver.findElement(By.name("userName")).sendKeys("invalidUN");
        driver.findElement(By.name("password")).sendKeys("invalidPW");
        driver.findElement(By.name("login")).click();
        System.out.println("login in progress");
    }

    @Test
    public final void flightFinder() {

        WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 30);
        WebElement oneWayRadioButton = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.linkText("oneway")));
        oneWayRadioButton.click();
        System.out.println("Clicked One Way");
    }

}
```

Any help would be deeply appreciated.

Comment: This website requires authorization, so you'd better add `HTML` for target radio-button to your question. Also check whether it's located inside an `iframe` and if so, provide with `HTML` for this `iframe`

Comment: it could be that linktext has some padding or something and it's not an exact match, try using by class or id.

Comment: Thanks for the inputs:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually the problem is in your test Methods

In `TestNG` the execution of `@Test` methods is in alphabetic order by default. So in your code  `flightFinder()` method executing before `login()` So even you are using right locator to click on radio button, It will show the exception.

**Solution:**

1. Maintains your method name in alphabetic order
2. Use priority under `@Test` annotation for the methods e.g. -  `@Test(priority = 1)`
3. Create dependency test e.g. -

   ```
   @Test()
   public final void login() 
   {
      //code
   }

   @Test(dependsOnMethods={"login"})
   public final void flightFinder() 
   {
       //code
   }
   ```

Update your code as below and try -

```
@Test
public final void doLogin() {

    driver.findElement(By.name("userName")).sendKeys("invalidUN");
    driver.findElement(By.name("password")).sendKeys("invalidPW");
    driver.findElement(By.name("login")).click();
    System.out.println("login in progress");
}

@Test()
public final void flightFinder() {

    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@type='radio' and @value='oneway']")).click();
    System.out.println("Clicked One Way");
}
```

Comment: Worked well for me..Thank you so much:)

Comment: @Ashley, please remember that tests are supposed to be independent of other tests. As Narendra suggested, the execution of tests alphabetically is only the default setting and could be changed.

Answer (score 1):

`//*[@type='radio']//*[@value='oneway']` - you're looking for an element of type radio and value oneway.. this xpath look for an element of type radio that has a child element with value oneway.

`//*[contains(@type,'radio')]` - you'll get multiple results for this

`//*[contains(text(),'oneway']` - the text is not oneway, only the value attribute is oneway, the text contains 'One Way'

`//input[@type='radio' AND @value='oneway']` - this should work if you change 'AND' to 'and'

Comment: Tried this xpath  "//input[@type='radio' and @value='oneway']"..But its not working. I am getting No such Element Exception.

Answer (score 1):

Following solution worked for me on the newtour site -

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("input[value='oneway']")).click();
```